# How to get a list of unrepeatable date from my db in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

in my db there are 5 fields (id, list_date, amount, total, m_from)

and contain data, for example :

> 1 - 1/1/2010 - 10 - 50 - 'example111'
>
> 1 - 1/1/2010 - 10 - 50 - 'example111'
>
> 1 - 1/4/2010 - 10 - 50 - 'example154
>
> 1 - 1/1/2010 - 10 - 50 - 'example111'
>
> 1 - 1/5/2010 - 10 - 50 - 'test'

I need to know how I can get dates from list_date but without repeatable dates like '1/1/2010, 1/5/2010, 1/4/2010'

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT list_date FROM table
```

Answer (score 0):

If i'm not mistaken you can use also `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT list_date FROM table GROUP BY list_date
```

Comment: You're not mistaken, but please don't use GROUP BY if you need DISTINCT. They are not the same. Sure, a GROUP BY may be 'optimized' to a DISTINCT internally, but it's just wrong.